# Talend tPostgreSQLSCD missing data

Tags: postgresql, talend, scd

I am using the Talend component tPostgreSQLSCD in order to update or insert on a database table. There doesn't seem to be any problem with the components just a strange error is occurring.

Basically the job gets run through a batch file so I cannot see the console output but after much testing I can see that all the rows get passed from my tMap to my SCD component. Just that all of the rows do not get inserted to the actual table. Out of on average 8000 rows 500 do not get inserted each morning. But when the job is then run individually in the morning the problem does not occur and the rows are entered to the database.

Has this problem occurred for anyone else or has anyone any insight on a possible fix for this.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. If more information is needed please ask.

Thanks

[image: SCD Component]

Comment: you have to give more details about your job..may be scd is intentionally ignoring records as nothing have changed in them...can you give more details about your scd condition, whether its scd1, 2...also you can use tlogrow or tfileoutputdelimited in between or after tpostgresSQLSCd to see data and rows getting passed.

Comment: hi @garpitmzn Its not a case that nothing has changed in the rows as they get inserted when the job is then ran manually in the morning(after the batch file has failed to enter all rows) I think it is just SCD type 1 as there is no history created and there is no option to choose a type in the tPostgreSQLSCD component. Using a flowmeter either side of my tMap I can see that the correct amount of rows are being passed to the SCD component but the the correct amount does not get output unless the job is run standalone.

Comment: Have also placed a tLogrow and tFileoutputDelimited after the SCD but it only captures rejects of which there are none

Comment: ok..can you give a snapshot of your tpostgresqlscd component..as it has type0, type1, type2 fields and these are what controls what kind of scd we are using..it will help if you can give a screenshot of your job and inside of tpostgessqlscd component

Comment: Hi @garpitmzn I have edited the original request to include the screenshot of the SCD I can see what you mean now all fields are type2

Comment: why is your surrogate key column empty..are you not using any surrogate key in your table..its difficult to help with data issue, as there is no error message here or any other problem..its a case where your rows are getting filtered..my suggestion would be that you try to keep only source_key, surrogate)key, and one column in your input and target along with startdate, enddate, versoin flag..then see if all works as you expect...I personally do not use scd2 component, as they do not give you control. I write my own scd2 logic using tmap...just go in iterations to debug and find issue

Comment: yes there is no surrogate key used as there is already a sequence built onto the table and the version flag is used as an identifier as the most up to date row where a quote number may be the same. Okay I will try using only 1 column and work my way down to see if the problem is in anyway column specific.however it will be tough as the problem only occurs when ran in a batch run and cannot reproduce it running the job individually :(